# Android 2 files found with path 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'. error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an app with Room, Retrofit and Hilt. When I run the app I get an error *2 files found with path 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'.* I've tried to clean and rebuild project but it didn't help. What can I do to solve the issue?

Gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
```

}

android {
namespace 'com.example.gymencv2'
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gymencv2"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
}
packagingOptions {
    resources {
        excludes += ('/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}')
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.1'

//Navigation component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

//Coil
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.2.2")

//Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

//Dagger-Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
```

},

````
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.3.2'
        nav_version = "2.5.3"
        room_version = "2.4.3"
        hilt_version = "2.44.2"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false

} ```
````

Answer (score 13):

Did you already figured this out? If not, maybe this can help you or others too!

You specified your dagger dependency like this:

```
//Dagger-Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Remove the implementation since it only needs kapt

Comment: It works for me but how do you come up with the solution from the error message?
'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'.
@ernesthor

Answer (score 3):

you use implementation for hilt compiler.
Try to use

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this block in **build.gradle.kts** inside android {} block, Worked for me.

```
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        excludes += "/META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors"

    }
}
```